# Issue with expiry month field skeuocard-rails (stripe)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using `skeuocard-rails` gem with `stripe` gem.

when I enter `13 in month` field  and `16 in year` it will update the params with `"cc_exp_month"=>"1", "cc_exp_year"=>"2017"`

I want to restrict month field to accept number less than 12.

when I try `$('input[name="cc_exp_month"]').val()` in firebug it always returns the new calculated value which is `1` instead of `13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this validating `cc-filed` in js on `focusout` event

```
 $('.cc-field').on('focusout', function() {
  if ($('.cc-field').find('input.cc-exp-field-m').val() > 12 || $(this).parents().find('.face').hasClass('filled invalid')) {
    / error handling
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```